# shell script to trim error_log files in all accounts in server

Tags: shell, cron, error-log

folks!

Here's my problem: I have a dedicated server using cPanel with several accounts hosted. About 20 of these accounts are generating huge error_log files daily, sometimes over 7 GB, which is using up all the account's disk space, not mentioning it's cluttering the server! I don't have the time or knowledge right now to find out and fix what's causing the problem in each one of these accounts. So I'd like a shell script that would trim/trucate these error_log files in all accounts to a maximum size of 500 kb, so they won't grow so large. And the cronjob to run it on a daily basis.

Can somebody help me with this?

TIA! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the truncate command to shrink or extend the size of each FILE to the specified size:

```
truncate -s 0 {filename.txt}
ls -lh filename.txt
truncate -s 0 filename.txt
ls -lh filename.txt
```

The -s option is used to set SIZE to zero. See truncate command man page for more details

```
man truncate
```

Comment: Tks for your reply. So that means I replace filename.txt with error_log and save this in a file to be called by cronjob? Will that affect every error-log in the server? Pardon my ignorance, I'm no programmer. :(

Comment: You can have a cron which runs regularly at fixed intervals and runs truncate command on the file names by which your logs are dumped.
That would truncate the log file.